# Compiler error in apex trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to write an apex trigger that will prevent accounts with opportunities from being deleted. I'm doing this through the new button on the trigger section of the account object.

Everytime I try to save, I'm getting either a compiler error or unexpected token. I'm brand new to apex and have little coding experience, any help would be appreciated!

```
trigger DeleteAccountOpportunity1 on Account (before delete)
{
List Opportunity__c = [Select accountID from opportunity where accountid in :TRIGGER.OLD];
for(Account a : Trigger.OLD)
{
for(Opportunity o : Opp)
{
if(a.id == o.accountId)
{
a.addError(Account have Opportunity ,so you can not delete this Account);
}
}
}
}
```

Edit: Error: Compile Error: Invalid identifier '‘Account'. Apex identifiers must start with an ASCII letter (a-z or A-Z) followed by any number of ASCII letters (a-z or A-Z), digits (0 - 9), '$', '_'. at line 10 column 12

Comment: Josh, could you please post one version of your trigger and the specific error message you're struggling with?

Comment: If you **[edit]** your post to include the specific error message(s) you encounter, I will reverse my down vote.

Comment: Is the code that you posted, all written in same trigger? That may be your issue.

Comment: addError missing quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there were few mistake in your code:-

**This is for your first trigger:-**

- List Opportunity__c = [Select accountID from opportunity where accountid in :TRIGGER.OLD];

You need to define List as follows:-

```
List<Opportunity> opp =[Select accountID from opportunity where accountid in :TRIGGER.OLD];
```

- You should avoid nested for loops in your code
- you should pass error message as string. i.e as follows:-

> a.addError('Account have Opportunity ,so you can not delete this
>   Account');

**This is for your second trigger:-**

1. Doing query inside for loop is not advisable, anytime you may hit the governor limit
2. You were querying on account and storing in Opportunity type
   variable.. Here you need to store the query in list of account.
   Also, When you are doing subquery on opportunity you need to provide
   plural name i.e Opportunities

***wrong***:-

```
   Opportunity oppprevent =[select Name,(select Name,Owner from Opportunitys)from ACCOUNT =: accdel.id ];
```

***Correct Way*** :-

```
  List< Account > acc= [select id,(select id,Accountid from Opportunities),Name from Account where id=:accdel.id];
```

Follow this one to achieve your requirement:-

```
trigger DeleteAccountOpportunity1 on Account (before delete) {
Map<id,Opportunity> mapAccWithOpp =new map<id,Opportunity>();
for(Opportunity opp:[select id,Accountid from Opportunity where Accountid in:trigger.old]){
    mapAccWithOpp.put(opp.AccountId,opp);
}
for(Account acc:trigger.old){
    if(mapAccWithOpp.containsKey(acc.id)){
        acc.addError('you cannot delete the account associated with opportunities');
    }
}
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you all for your advice, first time posting. I have added the actual error message from Salesforce.

Comment: Thank you Annappa and Sanket for commenting and adding advice.

Comment: Welcome @JoshDemumbreum, The error was because you were not defining the thing in the right way. I have pointed out all the things in my answer.